# Passing array in a c function using address operator gives a warning

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, gcc-warning

I was trying to pass an array to a method. I tried following ways:

1. func2(ARRAY_NAME, length) => WORKS, no warning
2. func2(&ARRAY_NAME[0], length) => WORKS, no warning
3. func2(&ARRAY_NAME, length) => WORKS, but WITH WARNING

I dont understand why the last one (#3) gives warning. &ARRAY_NAME works without warnings in memset, memcpy etc. Why its a problem in custom method?

WARNING message:

```
functionTest.c:35:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘func2’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   35 |     func2(&temp, ARRAY_SIZE);
      |           ^~~~~
      |           |
      |           unsigned char (*)[200]
functionTest.c:8:27: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char (*)[200]’
    8 | void func2(unsigned char* buf, int length)
```

CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ARRAY_SIZE 200

void func2(unsigned char* buf, int length) 
{
    // Change data of any index
    buf[0] = 100;
    buf[10] = 200;
}

void func1()
{
    unsigned char temp[ARRAY_SIZE]; 
    // Initialize
    memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d", temp[i]);
    }

    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Address : %p\n", &temp);
    printf("Address of 0th index : %p\n", &temp[0]);
    
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");

    // Pass array in func2  

    func2(&temp, ARRAY_SIZE); // WARNING

    func2(&temp[0], ARRAY_SIZE); // NO WARNING

    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("\t%d", temp[i]);
    }

    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------\n");
}

int main()
{
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pointer to element is not the same as pointer to array of element. That is what the message says. Memset(etc.) do not care about the type, it requires a pointer that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is clear written in the error message

```
functionTest.c:8:27: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char (*)[200]’
    8 | void func2(unsigned char* buf, int length)
```

the function expects a pointer of the type `unsigned char *` but the argument expression `&temp` has the type `unsigned char ( * )[200]` and there is no implicit conversion from one pointer type to another though values of the pointers are the same: the address of the extent of memory occupied by the array.

As for the functions `memset` and `memcpy` then they deal with pointers of the type `void *`. For example the function `memset` has the following declaration

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

And a pointer to object of other type can be implicitly converted to pointer of the type `void *`.

From the C Standard (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
> pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the
> original pointer.

Answer (score 3):

`func2` is declared to have a first parameter of type `unsigned char *`, so it should be passed a pointer to a type compatible with `unsigned char` or a pointer to `void`, which will be automatically converted to `unsigned char *`.

With `func2(temp, ARRAY_SIZE)`, the array `temp` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. This pointer is an `unsigned char *`, so it satisfies the requirements.

With `func2(&temp[0], ARRAY_SIZE)`, `temp[0]` is an `unsigned char`, so `&temp[0]` is a pointer to an `unsigned char`. This satisfies the requirements.

With `func2(&temp, ARRAY_SIZE)`, `&temp` is a pointer to an array of 200 elements of `unsigned char`. It points to the same place as `&temp[0]`, bit its type is different. It is a pointer to an array, not a pointer to `unsigned char` or to a compatible type nor a pointer to `void`. So it does not satisfy the requirements, and the compiler complains.

Pointers to `unsigned char` and pointers to arrays are different. If the type of `pu` is `unsigned char *` and the type of `pa` is `unsigned char (*)[200]` (a pointer to an array of 200 `unsigned char`), then adding 1 to `pu`, as in `pu + 1`, produces a pointer to the next `unsigned char` after `pu`, but adding 1 to `pa` produces a pointer to the next array after `pa`. In other words, `pu + 1` points to the next byte in memory, but `pa + 1` points 200 bytes further along in memory.

One purpose of C’s type system is to help avoid errors. When a non-matching type is passed to a function, the programmer may be expected some behavior other than what the language defines. So the compiler issues a diagnostic message.

With `memset`, its first parameter is declared to be `void *`. `void` is an incomplete type; it acts as a placeholder for other types. `memset` is designed to work on the bytes of any object, so it accepts a pointer to any object type. When any pointer to an object type is passed for a `void *` parameter, it is automatically converted to `void *`, without any diagnostic message.